# Add regex matches together

Tags: java, regex

I want to create a regex to match all the elements in the following string:

```
11 jan. 22:20 - Dam: Ik zal d'r zijn
```

I want to match the date, the time, the name (Dam) and the message.

Currently, I've got the following regexes:

```
checks date: [1-31 a-z]
checks message: ([^:]+)(.*)$
checks time: (([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9])
checks name: (?:\s[^:-]+)
```

How do I glue these together? I want to use it like this:

```
String date = matcher.group(1);
Time time = new Time(matcher.group(2));
String name = matcher.group(3);
Message message = new Message(matcher.group(4));
Chat chat = new Chat(date,time,name,message);
```

Also, the name doesn't only match the value after -\s but also the message and part of the time.

Comment: On which platform are you developing?  Looks rather Java 7, but want to be certain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d{1,2}\\s[a-z]{3})\\.?\\s(\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2})\\s-\\s([a-z]+):\\s(.+)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher m = p.matcher("11 jan. 22:20 - Dam: Ik zal d'r zijn");

    while (m.find())
    {
      for (int i=1; i <= m.groupCount(); ++i)
        System.out.println("group " + i + ": " + m.group(i));
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

> group 1: 11 jan
>   group 2: 22:20
>   group 3: Dam
>   group 4: Ik zal d'r zijn

Note from the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE):

> By default, case-insensitive matching assumes that only characters in
>   the US-ASCII charset are being matched. Unicode-aware case-insensitive
>   matching can be enabled by specifying the UNICODE_CASE flag in
>   conjunction with this flag.

You may want to capture the period after the month's name, in which case you'd move the closing round bracket.  You may also wish to include non-alpha characters in names, if so, update the `([a-z]+)` character class.

Links: [Regex101](https://www.regex101.com/r/nP4qZ3/1), [RegexPlanet Java](http://fiddle.re/daunq) (you'll have to manually check the CASE_INSENSITIVE flag when following that link, not sure why they don't preserve those in the share link).

Comment: Nice! Why /i and not /g? Also, how do I group match 1 and 2?

Comment: I also get a lot of escape errors btw, everywhere \ is used.

Comment: i is case insensitive.  If you're running logs, you'd also want to include g.  The round brackets are the borders of group matches, so just take out the closing bracket of the first and the opening bracket of the second to merge them.

Comment: Nice! I'm a bit confused about why I get errors on illegal escape characters while this regex compiles just fine: `"^(\\d\\d?[\\/-]\\d\\d?[\\/-]\\d{2,4}) (\\d\\d:\\d\\d:\\d\\d)(?: [ap]m)?: ([^:]+): (.*)$";`

Comment: Since java doesn't use /pattern/flags notation, I don't believe you need to escape the forward slash.

Comment: Hmm I'm sorry but your last edit doesn't seem to work on Regex101, as well as in my code. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Regex101 doesn't use java escaping.  I'll update with a full code example shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the regex string

```
([\\w\\s]+)([\\s\\.]*)([\\d:]+)([\\s\\-]*)([\\w]+)([\\s:]*)([\\s\\S]*)
```

Update regex

```
([\w\s]+)(?:[\s\.]*)([\d:]+)(?:[\s\-]*)([\w]+)(?:[\s:]*)([\s\S]*)
```

Check this link out https://regex101.com/r/cP8cU9/2

Test:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern
        .compile("([\\w\\s]+)(?:[\\s\\.]*)([\\d:]+)(?:[\\s\\-]*)([\\w]+)(?:[\\s:]*)([\\s\\S]*)");
Matcher matcher = pattern
        .matcher("11 jan. 22:20 - Dam: Ik zal d'r zijn");
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(String.format("Date: %s", matcher.group(1)));
    System.out.println(String.format("Time: %s", matcher.group(2)));
    System.out.println(String.format("Name: %s", matcher.group(3)));
    System.out.println(String.format("Message: %s", matcher.group(4)));
}
```

Or you can make a loop to get data

```
while (matcher.find()) {
    int groupCnt = matcher.groupCount();
    for (int i = 1; i <= groupCnt; i++) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

Check this link out: https://regex101.com/r/cP8cU9/1 to know how to get specify group. (Look into the right sidebar)

Result:

```
Date: 11 jan
Message: Ik zal d'r zijn
Time: 22:20
Name: Dam
```

Comment: Change the input string to `a1 jan. 22:20 - Dam: Ik zal d'r zijn` and your regex will give a false positive on the date.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jack, however, since I'm using multiple regexes in my code, the matcher.group() needs to be counting from 1 to 4 instead of making jumps.

Comment: It's very easy to edit, you just add ?: to group that you don't want to take it. See my update